# Jquery Selecting Multiple Classes, Loading External Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have 2 links, with the class dynamicLoad.

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="Page3-News.html" class="dynamicLoad news">NEWS</a></li>
    <li><a href="Page2-Events.html" class="dynamicLoad">EVENTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

and then I have this already working code, which loads external pages into a div named #MainWrapper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
            e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link

            $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
        });
    });

</script>
```

How do I edit this code and my links, so that i can target the 1st link with the classes of both dynamicLoad and news, and then, load another script and/or pages into the main wrapper, without breaking its already working functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can add both classes to the selector as well as [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a.dynamicLoad.news:first').click(function(e) {
        $('#MainWrapper').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

A [`return false;` calls both `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/event.js#L462-465), so you can slim down the code a bit for that...like I have above.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first link with `$( "a.dynamicLoad.news" )`

Comment: and for the rest of the question?